# Override OnBackKeyPress event in UserControl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

There is any other way through which I can close the usercontrol popup on back key
,In the simple page we can do this by OnBackKeyPress event.

Please go through the below. VehicalPopup is popup where I want to close this on backkey and cancel the navigation back from userconrol

```
  protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your work here
        // base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        if (VehicalPopUp.IsOpen)
        {
            Popup__ShowHide(false);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

UserControl doesnot onBackKeyPress Event please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done from the page in which the user control is used.

```
 if (UserControlName.VehicalPopUp.IsOpen)
        {
            UserControlName.Popup__ShowHide(false);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```